# Swift Class with an optional value

Tags: swift

How can I do the following:

I have a class in swift

```
class Book {
var title: String
var author: String?

init(title: String, author: String?) {
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
}
```

and in another class I'm making a call to an api to retrieve a list of books, sometimes though the author is not present so

```
let title: String? = getBookTitle()
let author: String? = getBookAuthor()

Book = new Book(title: book, author: author)
```

I'm not very confident about my approach, is this the right way to do it? because now I have to use (if let) every time I want to get the author of the book

Comment: In your data, will a book always have a title? Will it always have an author?

Comment: If you need a type only to store data and read some info consider using `struct` instead of `class`. You can read more about it here: [Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: I'm giving a simple example because I'm having doubts regarding using optionals

Comment: I will always have a title but not an author, I could make the title optional as well

Comment: @nevermind If the class must always have a `title`, then I would not advise making it an optional. That only makes the class unnecessary confusing, and not representative of the actual business rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
let title: String? = getBookTitle()
let author: String? = getBookAuthor()
```

There's presumably no point in making `title` optional, as you tell us it is always present, but it depends upon how `getBookTitle` was defined. Furthermore, if these methods were defined to return `String` or `String?`, as appropriate, then the type here could be inferred, yielding:

```
let title  = getBookTitle()
let author = getBookAuthor()
```

Next, you have:

```
Book = new Book(title: book, author: author)
```

But, the instantiation of the new `Book` object needs a variable name (and the `new` keyword is not needed), yielding:

```
let book = Book(title: book, author: author)
```

(Use `let` if you're going to set this local `book` variable once within this scope. If you're going to reset it again and again without leaving this function, use `var`. Bottom line, use `let` whenever you can.)

Finally, you say:

> is this the right way to do it? because now I have to use (`if let`) every time I want to get the author of the book.

Yes, it is appropriate to use an optional for `author`. And, yes, that means that you have to unwrap this optional with `if let` or equivalent syntax when you want to use it. Note, you don't have to do the optional binding syntax, `if let`, if you don't want, but rather you could just use `if` and then perform forced unwrapping (e.g. the `!`), if you want. But you need to unwrap it one way or the other.

You technically could use an implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`), and it would be automatically unwrapped every time you use it. But I think the standard optional syntax makes the meaning more clear (specifically, that the `author` may be `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

Works of me:

```
import UIKit

class Book {

    var title: String
    var author: String?

    init(title: String, author: String?) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getBookTitle()
        getBookAuthor()
        var book = Book(title: "A Tale of Two Cities", author: "Charles Dickens")

    }

    func getBookTitle() {
    }

    func getBookAuthor() {
    }

}
```